# Как поместить экземпляр класса в HashMap

Tags: java

Есть класс Flat:

```
 public class Flat{
        private int door; /3
        private int window; /4
        private int room; /6
        }
```

Как возможно поместить экземпляр класса Flat в HashMap, чтобы ключами были поля (door, window, room), а значения - соответственно значения (3,4,6)
Спасибо!

Comment: зачем? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709

Comment: Возможно Вам больше подойдет enum.

Comment: Именно нужен HashMap. То есть это сложно реализовать?

Comment: @Matty что вы подразумеваете под "ключами были поля"? Чтобы ключами были строки, значения которых совпадают с именами полей?

Comment: @Regent, ключ - дверь, а значение - 3.

Comment: @Matty ещё раз: "дверь" - это что будет? Строка (`String`) или что? Какой тип объекта (какой класс) будет являться ключом в `HashMap`? Что значение `Integer` - понятно.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("door", 3);
map.put("window", 4);
map.put("room", 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Рефлексию используй, если хочешь остроты, или так проще всего:

```
    Map<Flat, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(Flat.door, 3);
    map.put(Flat.window, 3);
    map.put(Flat.room, 3);
```

Comment: Flat - это enum, а не class

Comment: и дополни ответ, чтобы в enum конструктор принимал класс и integer. и название enum должно быть другим